# How to update the display in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning Kotlin, and this is my first Kotlin. So please bear with me.

So, I have this data class:

```
data class Order(
    var title: String,
    var qty: Int,
    var price: Int
) {
    val total: Int
        get() {
            return qty * price
        }
}
```

and I've created this service to deal with order:

```
class OrderService {
    val orders: MutableList<Order> = mutableListOf()

    fun addOrder(order: Order) {
        orders.add(order)
        println(order);
        println(orders.count())
    }
}
```

Then I modified the example to be like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Learn1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val orderService = OrderService()
                    var counters = remember {
                        MutableStateFlow(orderService)
                    }
                    OrderCards(itemList = orderService.orders)
                    AddButton {
                        counters.apply {
                            orderService.addOrder(Order("newItem", 100, 20))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OrderCards(itemList: List<Order>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(items = itemList) {
            ItemCard(item = it)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemCard(item: Order) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 4.dp)
    ) {
        Column {
            Text(text = "Date: ${item.title}")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AddButton(action: () -> Unit) {
    Box {
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = action,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.BottomEnd)
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
        }
    }
}
```

I saw some examples on how to use Flow, but I am not sure on how to implement it, and I am sure that I did something wrong there, since the screen obviously didn't update after I pressed the button.

The addButton works, because I can see that the order list adding. It just didn't update the screen

Can someone please help me on how to update the screen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

> ```
> val orders: MutableList<Order> = mutableListOf()
> ```

needs to be a [`mutableStateListOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/MutableState) like:

```
val orders = mutableStateListOf<Order>()
```

Without `State` the simple `MutableList` list not observable.

> A mutable value holder where reads to the value property during the execution of a Composable function, the current RecomposeScope will be subscribed to changes of that value. When the value property is written to and changed, a recomposition of any subscribed RecomposeScopes will be scheduled. If value is written to with the same value, no recompositions will be scheduled.

Also this:

> ```
> val orderService = OrderService()
> ```

should be:

```
 val orderService = remember { OrderService() }
```

Otherwise the `OrderService` is being reset everytime recomposition takes place.

See [State in composables](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) for a detailed description how it works.

> Composable functions can use the remember API to store an object in memory. A value computed by remember is stored in the Composition during initial composition, and the stored value is returned during recomposition. remember can be used to store both mutable and immutable objects.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. So.. `remember` doesn't mean to "remember" the state, but instead to `remember` between recomposition. But is it a good idea to put state inside a service? Shouldn't it exists outside service?

Comment: Now that I understand a bit how that works, in term of best practice, is it better to do it like it was, inside service, or make it a normal mutableList, and put a copy as state at composables, then put the service as class variable scope?

Comment: You can leave it inside the service. I do this too. This way it's easier to organize the data,especially when you later have several of them. And you need only a single remember this way. Otherwise you'd have to write multiple remembers, one for each state.

Answer (score 1):

`val orderService = OrderService()` -> this line is inside a composable function. when you click a button on ui, composable functions runs again and a new orderService creating over and over. You should use side effects or move this logic to ViewModel. Compose is a bit harder to learn for new learners.

Comment: How do I use ViewModel? The very first time I started Android Studio, and chose blank Activity, the gave me this template. I've successfully  played around with adding or manipulating some items to some degree. But I still don't understand what's underneath it.

Comment: @Magician your service is actually the view-model here. You just gave it a different name :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t yeah, actually it is how I write View-Model in other languages, but I am not sure how it works in Kotlin and Android.